# kubectl get pods does not show the kube-apiserver pod, but crictl pods does show it - how is it possible?

Tags: kubernetes

I have a weird situation on my kubeadm k8s cluster.

`crictl` says I have the `kube-apiserver-cks-master` pod running in the `kube-system` namespace:

```
mark@cks-master:~ $ sudo crictl ps -a | grep kube-apiserver
175ba4b6a69fd       deb04688c4a35       15 minutes ago      Running             kube-apiserver            0                   a420a930ca851       kube-apiserver-cks-master
mark@cks-master:~ $ sudo crictl pods --id a420a930ca851
POD ID              CREATED             STATE               NAME                        NAMESPACE           ATTEMPT             RUNTIME
a420a930ca851       15 minutes ago      Ready               kube-apiserver-cks-master   kube-system         0                   (default)
mark@cks-master:~ $
```

But checking the namespace with `kubectl` does not find the pod!

```
mark@cks-master:~ $ k get pod -n kube-system kube-apiserver-cks-master
Error from server (NotFound): pods "kube-apiserver-cks-master" not found
mark@cks-master:~ $ k get pod -n kube-system
NAME                                       READY   STATUS    RESTARTS         AGE
calico-kube-controllers-58dbc876ff-ltczk   1/1     Running   61 (16m ago)     120d
canal-lm2z4                                2/2     Running   55 (7h10m ago)   126d
canal-xhfjr                                2/2     Running   58 (7h9m ago)    126d
coredns-787d4945fb-cxvqr                   1/1     Running   27 (7h9m ago)    120d
coredns-787d4945fb-s4ng8                   1/1     Running   27 (7h9m ago)    120d
etcd-cks-master                            1/1     Running   24 (7h9m ago)    68d
kube-controller-manager-cks-master         1/1     Running   29 (20m ago)     67d
kube-proxy-ppvn4                           1/1     Running   27 (7h10m ago)   126d
kube-proxy-xdkwm                           1/1     Running   29 (7h9m ago)    126d
kube-scheduler-cks-master                  1/1     Running   30 (20m ago)     68d
mark@cks-master:~ $
```

I have never seen anything like that.

Now I did modify the kube-apiserver static pod - I added an ImagePolicyWebhook as part of an exercise. But it does not explain this behavior, does it?

Anyway, here is the YAML for the kube-apiserver just in case:

```
mark@cks-master:~ $ sudo cat /etc/kubernetes/manifests/kube-apiserver.yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  annotations:
    kubeadm.kubernetes.io/kube-apiserver.advertise-address.endpoint: 10.0.0.4:6443
  creationTimestamp: null
  labels:
    component: kube-apiserver
    tier: control-plane
  name: kube-apiserver
  namespace: kube-system
spec:
  containers:
  - command:
    - kube-apiserver
    - --admission-control-config-file=/etc/kubernetes/config/admission-configuration.yaml
    - --encryption-provider-config=/etc/kubernetes/enc/enc.yaml
    - --advertise-address=10.0.0.4
    - --allow-privileged=true
    - --authorization-mode=Node,RBAC
    - --client-ca-file=/etc/kubernetes/pki/ca.crt
    - --enable-admission-plugins=NodeRestriction,ImagePolicyWebhook
    - --enable-bootstrap-token-auth=true
    - --etcd-cafile=/etc/kubernetes/pki/etcd/ca.crt
    - --etcd-certfile=/etc/kubernetes/pki/apiserver-etcd-client.crt
    - --etcd-keyfile=/etc/kubernetes/pki/apiserver-etcd-client.key
    - --etcd-servers=https://127.0.0.1:2379
    - --kubelet-client-certificate=/etc/kubernetes/pki/apiserver-kubelet-client.crt
    - --kubelet-client-key=/etc/kubernetes/pki/apiserver-kubelet-client.key
    - --kubelet-preferred-address-types=InternalIP,ExternalIP,Hostname
    - --proxy-client-cert-file=/etc/kubernetes/pki/front-proxy-client.crt
    - --proxy-client-key-file=/etc/kubernetes/pki/front-proxy-client.key
    - --requestheader-allowed-names=front-proxy-client
    - --requestheader-client-ca-file=/etc/kubernetes/pki/front-proxy-ca.crt
    - --requestheader-extra-headers-prefix=X-Remote-Extra-
    - --requestheader-group-headers=X-Remote-Group
    - --requestheader-username-headers=X-Remote-User
    - --secure-port=6443
    - --service-account-issuer=https://kubernetes.default.svc.cluster.local
    - --service-account-key-file=/etc/kubernetes/pki/sa.pub
    - --service-account-signing-key-file=/etc/kubernetes/pki/sa.key
    - --service-cluster-ip-range=10.96.0.0/12
    - --tls-cert-file=/etc/kubernetes/pki/apiserver.crt
    - --tls-private-key-file=/etc/kubernetes/pki/apiserver.key
    - --tls-min-version=VersionTLS12
    - --tls-cipher-suites=TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
    image: registry.k8s.io/kube-apiserver:v1.26.1
    imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
    livenessProbe:
      failureThreshold: 8
      httpGet:
        host: 10.0.0.4
        path: /livez
        port: 6443
        scheme: HTTPS
      initialDelaySeconds: 10
      periodSeconds: 10
      timeoutSeconds: 15
    name: kube-apiserver
    readinessProbe:
      failureThreshold: 3
      httpGet:
        host: 10.0.0.4
        path: /readyz
        port: 6443
        scheme: HTTPS
      periodSeconds: 1
      timeoutSeconds: 15
    resources:
      requests:
        cpu: 250m
    startupProbe:
      failureThreshold: 24
      httpGet:
        host: 10.0.0.4
        path: /livez
        port: 6443
        scheme: HTTPS
      initialDelaySeconds: 10
      periodSeconds: 10
      timeoutSeconds: 15
    volumeMounts:
    - mountPath: /etc/kubernetes/config
      name: config
      readOnly: true
    - mountPath: /etc/kubernetes/enc
      name: enc
      readOnly: true
    - mountPath: /etc/ssl/certs
      name: ca-certs
      readOnly: true
    - mountPath: /etc/ca-certificates
      name: etc-ca-certificates
      readOnly: true
    - mountPath: /etc/pki
      name: etc-pki
      readOnly: true
    - mountPath: /etc/kubernetes/pki
      name: k8s-certs
      readOnly: true
    - mountPath: /usr/local/share/ca-certificates
      name: usr-local-share-ca-certificates
      readOnly: true
    - mountPath: /usr/share/ca-certificates
      name: usr-share-ca-certificates
      readOnly: true
  hostNetwork: true
  priorityClassName: system-node-critical
  securityContext:
    seccompProfile:
      type: RuntimeDefault
  volumes:
  - hostPath:
      path: /etc/kubernetes/config
      type: DirectoryOrCreate
    name: config
  - hostPath:
      path: /etc/kubernetes/enc
      type: DirectoryOrCreate
    name: enc
  - hostPath:
      path: /etc/ssl/certs
      type: DirectoryOrCreate
    name: ca-certs
  - hostPath:
      path: /etc/ca-certificates
      type: DirectoryOrCreate
    name: etc-ca-certificates
  - hostPath:
      path: /etc/pki
      type: DirectoryOrCreate
    name: etc-pki
  - hostPath:
      path: /etc/kubernetes/pki
      type: DirectoryOrCreate
    name: k8s-certs
  - hostPath:
      path: /usr/local/share/ca-certificates
      type: DirectoryOrCreate
    name: usr-local-share-ca-certificates
  - hostPath:
      path: /usr/share/ca-certificates
      type: DirectoryOrCreate
    name: usr-share-ca-certificates
status: {}
mark@cks-master:~ $
```

Finally, proving that I am using the right kubeconfig:

```
mark@cks-master:~ $ k config view
apiVersion: v1
clusters:
- cluster:
    certificate-authority-data: DATA+OMITTED
    server: https://10.0.0.4:6443
  name: kubernetes
contexts:
- context:
    cluster: kubernetes
    namespace: default
    user: kubernetes-admin
  name: kubernetes-admin@kubernetes
current-context: kubernetes-admin@kubernetes
kind: Config
preferences: {}
users:
- name: kubernetes-admin
  user:
    client-certificate-data: DATA+OMITTED
    client-key-data: DATA+OMITTED
mark@cks-master:~ $ k get node -o wide
NAME         STATUS   ROLES           AGE    VERSION   INTERNAL-IP   EXTERNAL-IP   OS-IMAGE             KERNEL-VERSION      CONTAINER-RUNTIME
cks-master   Ready    control-plane   126d   v1.26.1   10.0.0.4      <none>        Ubuntu 20.04.6 LTS   5.15.0-1040-azure   containerd://1.6.12
cks-worker   Ready    <none>          126d   v1.26.1   10.0.0.5      <none>        Ubuntu 20.04.5 LTS   5.15.0-1040-azure   containerd://1.6.12
mark@cks-master:~ $
```

Can someone explain what is going on?